# How to change Indentation Line Color In Android Studio 4.0?

Tags: android-studio

I don't know what the name of this setting is. It's the (grayish) line that appears when you unfold a method, if, for, etc.. statement (see attached image). I want to change the color but can't find the option in the Android Studio 4.0 settings menu. Does anyone know what's it called and how to change it's color?
thanks

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things have changed in android studio 4.0

In order to change the color of that indentation line do this

```
Go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> General
```

And inside that go to `Editor -> Guides`

You can set

- Indent Guide
- Indent Guide Selected

[image: Here is the image of it]

Output Image : 
[image]